# Rails - Parse error in migration, but only on some systems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

I've written a migration to populate a countries table with fairly static data.

It works fine on one of my machines (Rails 3.0.something, Ruby 1.9.something, Windows 7) but not on another (Rails 3.0.5, Ruby 1.8.7, OSX Snow Leopard). It gives me the following error:

/path_to_webapp/db/migrate/20110404132215_add_countries.rb:267: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting $end

It's not to do with the accented characters on some of the countries' names because the error still happens if I delete them all except Afghanistan and Zimbabwe, although I did have to convert the file to UTF8 to make it parse on the Windows box because it didn't like Côte d'Ivoire.

```
class AddCountries < ActiveRecord::Migration

  # Use a copy of the Country class so we can add some without worrying about anything that may change on the model down the line
  class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  end

  def self.up
    Country.new({:name => "Afghanistan", :two_letter_code => "AF", :three_letter_code => "AFG"}).save
    Country.new({:name => "Åland Islands", :two_letter_code => "AX", :three_letter_code => "ALA"}).save
    Country.new({:name => "Albania", :two_letter_code => "AL", :three_letter_code => "ALB"}).save
    Country.new({:name => "Algeria", :two_letter_code => "DZ", :three_letter_code => "DZA"}).save
  end

  def self.down
    Country.all().destroy
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated to Ruby 1.9.x and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

You should put:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

At the very top of your page.

Comment: I'm now getting this error: rake aborted! undefined local variable or method `' for main:Object. Any ideas?

Comment: It appears that Rails really doesn't like having anything at the top of its migrations. If I put anything before the class keyword, even a space or a newline, it dies with that error. I'm tempted to try upgrading to Ruby 1.9 seeing as that works fine on my Windows box.